# Facebook fbq('track' 'lead') in angular 4 to track specific page

Tags: angular, typescript, facebook-pixel

Im using angular 4 and I simply want detect how many times users complete form until **successful registration** page. But i cannot see / detect anything after done some successful registration. Can anyone tell me where i made mistake? This is method im using:

**success-page.component.ts**

```js
constructor(public router: Router) {
  this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      fbq('track', 'Lead');
    }
  });
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<script>
  ! function(f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
    if (f.fbq) return;
    n = f.fbq = function() {
      n.callMethod ?
        n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
    };
    if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
    n.push = n;
    n.loaded = !0;
    n.version = '2.0';
    n.queue = [];
    t = b.createElement(e);
    t.async = !0;
    t.src = v;
    s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
  }(window, document, 'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '256905991728678');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
```

Comment: This method already correct. Just make sure turn off ad blocker extension. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the "Lead" event into with your facebook script. The below facebook script is fine. Now your calling of fB script is wrong. Just use the other calling method so that above the "lead" event you can cal the FB script.